# Jquery Ajax Undefined Error

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, undefined

```
$.ajax({
    async: false, 
    url:’<?php echo base_url(‘abc/demo/sample_foo’); ?>’,
    success: function(result){
    if(result.responseText == true)
      alert(“random text”);
    else
      alert(“some_other_random_text”);
  }
  });
```

In demo controller function sample_foo() returns true or false values only, but when i alert it shows "Undefined"
What can i do to retrive true and false value ?

Comment: what is written in sample_foo() ?
please clarify your question and post function code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about php, but those quotes are going to cause issues:

rewrite as:

```
  '<?php echo base_url("abc/demo/sample_foo"); ?>'
```

or

```
  "<?php echo base_url('abc/demo/sample_foo'); ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to make sure the url exists 
if it alerts "page not found" or "err" then check the url

```
$.ajax({
 url:'your_url',
 statusCode: {
 404: function() {
   alert("page not found");
  }
 },
 success:function(){
    alert("scss")
 }, error:function(){
     alert("err")
 }
 });
```

​

also you need to check the console in google chrome or firebug in FF , if you find and error with the url that you are requesting then you should make sure of your url again

Answer (score 0):

first step to use a absolute URL such as `http://127.0.0.1/abc/demo/sample_foo`, if it's work, then rewrite the url parameter in ajax:

```
url:"<?php echo base_url('abc/demo/sample_foo'); ?>"
```

or:

```
url: "<?php echo base_url().'demo/sample_foo'; ?>"
```

if what i said above doesn't work, try modify your single quotes to double quotes, Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

Put in failure function, is the request reaching the function?